# Отображение изображения созданного посредством php и полученного через js

Tags: php, javascript, изображения

Сайт отправляет через js на php скрипт некие данные, там они заносятся на картинку, далее скрипт возвращает картинку (но, увы, в виде текста - кулебяки)
Как можно отобразить полученную картинку на странице?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть пара вариантов решения данной проблемы:

1. Записать картинку в файл и вернуть URL к этому файлу
2. Base64 Encoded String картинки. Этот код можно вставить как *src* тэга *img*

   ob_start();

   imagepng($image);

   $image_data = ob_get_contents();

   ob_end_clean();

   $encoded = base64_encode($image_data);

`$encoded` возвращаете клиенту

Comment: То есть полученую кракозябру прогнать через base64?

Comment: Не кракозябру. Как только получаете картинку, закодировать ее в base64. И уже полученный код вернуть в ответе

Comment: imagepng($img_res); 
Ну вот у меня создалась картинка, как мне её закодировать

Comment: дополнил ответ примером кода

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сохранять изображение и возвращать путь к этому изображению на сервере.

Тут главное чтобы сохранялась графика в директорию, доступную для чтения.

Comment: Сохранять не вариант. Слишком муторно, нужно будет же потом её потереть.

Comment: А в чем проблема её не тереть, а перезаписывать с тем же именем?? Если не кэшировать изображения  то проблем не будет. Я так реализовывал статистику на карту России, когда нужно было динамичные цифры выводить в строгих точках карты, независимо от экрана устройства просмотра. Решение с перезапись изображения по хрону каждые 2 минуты оказалось самым стабильным. У меня не было js для обновления в реал тайме, но изображение на стороне сервера перерисовывалось